# How to prove that $\varphi$ is an injective homomorphism and why it is surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, group-presentation

Here is the question I want to solve:

Prove that the subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb F_3)$ generated by $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ is isomorphic to the quaternion group of order $8.$[use a presentation for $\mathcal{Q}_8$]

Here is a solution I found online:

A presentation for $\mathcal{Q}_8,$ is $$\langle i,j | i^2 = j^2, i^4 = 1, ij = -ji \rangle$$
Which means that $i,j$ generates $\mathcal{Q}_8$ and they satisfy the relations $i^2 = j^2, i^4 = 1, ji = -ij = i^3j.$

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$ Define $\varphi: \{i,j\} \rightarrow \langle A, B \rangle $
as $\varphi(i) = A$ and $\varphi(j) = B.$

Now, note that by direct calculation , the subgroup generated by $A$ is  $$\langle A \rangle = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \}$$
And also, by direct calculation , the subgroup generated by $B$ is  $$\langle B \rangle = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \}$$
And it is clear that $|A|=|B| = 4$ and $A^2 = B^2.$\

Also, by direct calculation, we have that $BA = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} = A^3B.$

Here by the lemma $\varphi$ extends to an injective homomorphism $$\bar{\varphi} : \mathcal{Q}_8 \rightarrow \langle A, B \rangle $$
Also, by construction $\bar{\varphi}$ is surjective. Hence the required is proved.

**My questions are:**

1-I do not know what lemma says that $\varphi$ is an injective homomorphism, tthis problem is #10 in section 2.4 of Dummit and Foote (3rd edition) and I could not find any lemma that said this. Could anyone help me in proving that $\varphi$ is an injective homomorphism please?

2- Why by construction is $\bar{\varphi}$ is surjective? what confuses me is that $\langle A, B \rangle $ is the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$ and not the set that contains $A$ and $B,$ Could anyone explain to me this please?

Comment: What matters here is that $BA=-AB$, not that $BA=A^3B$. And $\varphi$ is not a homomorphism; its domain isn't a group.

Comment: So how can I correct the above solution? @JoséCarlosSantos could you provide me with some details please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $A^2=B^2$, $A^4=\operatorname{Id}_2$, and that $AB=-BA$. So, since $\mathcal Q_8$ since the group generated by two generators $i$ and $j$ and by the relations $i^2=j^2$, $i^4=e$, and $ij=-ji$, there is a surjective group homomorphism $\varphi$  from $\mathcal Q_8$ onto the subgroup $G$ of $SL_2(\Bbb F_3)$ spanned by $A$ and $B$. But $\mathcal Q_8$ and $G$ have $8$ elements each. Therefore, $\varphi$ is a bijection.

Comment: what do you mean by the index $2$ in $Id_2$?

Comment: How do you know that there is a surjective group homomorphism $\varphi$? which theorem or lemma did you use from the book?

Comment: Can you write the formula for this surjective group homomorphism map?

Comment: I mean the $2\times2$ identity matrix, that is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: How did you know that $G$ have $8$ elements?

Comment: $$G=\left\{\operatorname{Id}_2,A,-\operatorname{Id}_2,-A,B,\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix},-B\right\}$$

Comment: I do not have a copy of that book at hand. I used the fact that if you define a group $G$ as a presentation, that is, using a set of generators and a set of relations, than, if $H$ is any group generated by the seme number of generators and if the same relations hold for $H$, then there is a surjective group homomorphism from $G$ onto $H$.

Comment: Okay thank you!

Comment: what about the elements $A^3B$ and $B^3A$ are not those also in the group $G$?

Comment: And they are. But $A^2=B^2=-\operatorname{Id}_2$. So, $A^3B=-AB=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&-1\\-1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. A similar computation shows that $B^3A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: @Brain One easy way to see there are 8 elements in $G$ is that you already found $6$ elements.  The kernel of $\varphi$ is a subgroup of $Q_8$ so if it was non-trivial then there would be $4$ or fewer elements in the image.

Comment: @ErickWong what theorem leads you to say that?

Comment: @Brain I suppose it is essentially the first isomorphism theorem, together with the obvious fact that for finite groups, $|G/H| = |G|/|H|$.